# outputting html reports using .rspec file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to rspec testing.

I have a folder which contains _spec.rb files. When I run the specs using:

```
rspec --format html --out rspec_results.html "/Users/phukb/prpc-platform/prpc-platform/test/giza/coreui/ClientPerformance/RDL/spec/"
```

I see that the tests are run successfully and the results are posted in `rspec_results.html`.

However, when I create a `.rspec` file in my project with:

```
--format html --out rspec_results.html
```

and run the specs using

```
rspec "/Users/phukb/Desktop/prpc-platform/prpc-platform/test/giza/coreui/runtime_regression/featuresets/DynamicLayout/Repeating/MicroDC/Pagination/spec"
```

I see that the results_rspec.html is not getting created. Am I missing something here?

[here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atkv2.png)

Comment: Is the `.rspec` file in the project's root directory?

Comment: @LauraPaakkinen, yes.it seems to be.

Comment: Do you have a `.rspec-local`file in the root directory? Configuration in that file would take over the `.rspec` configuration.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files

Comment: @LauraPaakkinen, sorry for replying late. I dont have a .rspec-local file in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the `rspec` command from `../RDL` folder,then the `.rspec` file should also be there.

That is, the path of the file should be `../RDL/.rspec`, not `../RDL/spec/.rspec`.